# Qt. Не считываются данные из сокета.

Tags: tcp-ip, qt, c++, сокет

Здравствуйте. У меня проблема со считыванием данных из сокета. Я работаю с протоколом mrim. Поизучав поведение протокола в сниффе, понял, что при подключении к серверу mrim.mail.ru, он возвращает сервер для подключения и дальнейшей авторизации и т.п. Так вот, я подключаюсь к mrim.mail.ru, ну а дальше на основе примеров из книги считываю данные с сокета (должен считаться сервер и порт для авторизации), вот только когда я их вывожу в QTextEdit info, у меня ничего не выводится. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. Вот этот кусок кода из класса:

```
void mrim::connectToServer()
{

  tcpSocket.connectToHost("mrim.mail.ru", 2042);

  QString ip;
  QDataStream in(&tcpSocket);

  in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_3);
  in >> ip;
  info->append(ip);
}
```

Comment: Про qt ничего сказать не могу, а ncat читает, и сокет тут же закрывается со стороны mrim

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/ig/web-agent$ ncat mrim.mail.ru 2042
    94.100.189.191:2041
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/ig/web-agent$ 

Но эта информация вряд ли Вам поможет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А слоты на сигналы кто вешать будет?

```
//В конструкторе вешаете слот на чтение данных
connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));

void MyClass::slotReadyRead(){
    QString packet = tcpSocket->readAll ();
}
```